# Compare effect sizes in GLM, in order to do species grouping

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, effect-size

In an analysis of mine in ecology, I'm trying to quantify the effect of some crop surface on the abundance of several species. What I'd actually like to do is to see if the effect of crop surface is different among species in order to, later, group the species according to that effect and see if the species within a group share some interesting characteristics.

For simplification, let's say I have two species (S1,S2) and two regressors, my regressor of interest "crop" and another one, "X2".
My first idea was to fit a GLM with this formula :

[image: Formula]

where "Ab" is "abundance". With that method, I would compare the slopes beta5 and beta6, corresponding to the interaction between "crop" and each species.
But after searching a little over the forum it seems it's not such a good idea, because the size of the coefficient is not equivalent to the magnitude of the effect. So my question is, had I be better fitting one model per species, like this :

[image]

and then to find a way to calculate an "eta-squared" or something equivalent for the effect "crop", with confidence intervals, and then compare all the "eta-squared" for each species ? I mean, does it have sense to do this to answer my question or am I missing something ?

I'm not asking you to do my job of course but a little insight would be very appreciated.